# echo -e content of file fetched using foreach

Tags: php, foreach, echo

Forgive me, I'm not a programmer.

I am trying to include the last lines of a log file on a PHP page with two line breaks after each line read. Using responses from other questions, I came up with the following:

```
$file = "error.log";

foreach(file($file) as $line) {
        echo -e $line. "\n\n";
}
```

When I execute this on the command line using `php file.php`, it is displayed correctly with the line breaks, however, on a webpage, it ignores the line breaks and prints a dirty output.

I tried to use `echo -e` in place of `echo`, but that doesn't even present the dirty output, but instead throws an error:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$line' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/err.php on line 12`

I'm assuming `echo -e` isn't allowed within the foreach function? What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve the desired results?

Comment: what do you have before `$file = 'error.log'` ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix The opening tag (`<?php`).

Comment: you have something before `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$line' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/err.php on line 12` which the php interpreter doesn't like.

Comment: @VasilShaddix I do. It's `echo -e $line. "\n\n";`. The interpreter doesn't want `-e` as `echo` works fine. All I need is for the line breaks to show in the page when accessed via the browser.

Comment: Have you tried using `PHP_EOL ` or `< br> ` ?

Comment: `echo` in PHP is not the same `echo` you may know from the command line. PHP's `echo` doesn't take any `-` parameters.

Comment: A web page uses HTML to display it's contents. Normal line-breaks are ignored. So you need to add a HTML linebreak where you want it: <br/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` in PHP is different than the `echo` command line in linux. You can't pass arguments to echo in PHP like that.

try :

```
echo nl2br($line . PHP_EOL);
```

Or if you only care about the browser

```
echo $line . "<br>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it! :)